# How to disable tooltip when hovering over string literal in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Whenever I move my mouse over a line that I want to jump to when editing shader code inside a string literal, a huge tooltip appears that makes it very difficult for me to edit the text.

[image]

I have tried disabling inline hints like below, but that did not change anything.

[image]

Is it even possible to disable this in Visual Studio 2022?